# While loop not repeating in java

Tags: java

A program that takes ticket orders and provides the total. It's not letting me answer the question whether, i would like to buy more tickets. I'm a beginner, If you guys could guide me or suggest any upgrades that would be helpful.

```
package ridecalc;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**  *
   1. @author   */
public class Ridecalc {

 /**
  * @param args the command line arguments
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO code application logic here
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  double tickets = 0;
  double totprice;
  String moretickets = "";
  System.out.println("Hi! welcome to JP's amusment park");
  do {
   if (response()) {
    System.out.println("How many tickets would you like to purchase ?");
    tickets = in.nextInt();
   } else {
    totprice = 0;
   }
   totprice = calc(tickets);
   System.out.println("The total amount for the tickets are :" + totprice);
   System.out.println("Would you like to buy more tickets ?(y/n)");
   moretickets = in.nextLine();
  } while (moretickets.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
 }

 public static boolean response() {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  String response = "";
  System.out.println("Would you like to buy any tickets (y/n)");
  response = in.nextLine();
  if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
   return true;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }

 public static double calc(double tickets) {
  double totprice;
  totprice = (tickets * 20);
  return totprice;
 }
}
```

List item

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. could you edit the code so it is more readable?

Comment: `if (<xpr>) return true; else return false;` should be reduced to `return <expr>;` , also `if (<expr2> == true)` should be `if (<expr2>)` (`<expr>` and `<expr2>` stands for any expression that results in boolean {method call, logic expression, variable, ...})

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")` never evaluates to true because it is always an empty string, there has been no affectation to the variable `response`. So I added a `boolean rps` that will store the response of the user from your function `response()` and loop until it is true.

**EDIT: Fixed usage of Scanner, only one Scanner instance**
**EDIT 2: Fixed double condition**

```
package ridecalc;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**  *
   1. @author   */
public class some {

 /**
  * @param args the command line arguments
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO code application logic here
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  double tickets = 0;
  double totprice;
  String moretickets = "";
  System.out.println("Hi! welcome to JP's amusment park");

  boolean rps = true;
  while( rps ){
   if ( (rps = response(in)) == true) {
    System.out.println("How many tickets would you like to purchase ?");
    tickets = in .nextInt();
   } else {
    totprice = 0;
   }
   totprice = calc(tickets);
   System.out.println("The total amount for the tickets are :" + totprice);
   System.out.println("Would you like to buy more tickets ?(y/n)");     // this doesn't seem necessary since there is no test following
   in.next();
   moretickets = in.nextLine();
  }
 }

 public static boolean response(Scanner in) {
  String response = "";
  System.out.println("Would you like to buy any tickets (y/n)");
  response = in.nextLine();
  if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    System.err.println("here");
   return true;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }

 public static double calc(double tickets) {
  double totprice;
  totprice = (tickets * 20);
  return totprice;
 }
}
```

Comment: good point..me and my effort to make the most minimal changes backfiring haahaha

Comment: That is a fair approach, and no harm was done! You might mention that you fixed that part in your answer though.

Comment: feels like i have a mentor on SO :D

Comment: @simptri you can directly check response using if (response()) here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I ran the code above but, the text  "Would you like to buy any tickets" is being asked twice.

Comment: my mistake, i called `response()` twice

Comment: see my comment on question

Comment: I am always glad to help :-)

Comment: Thank you very much guys. You guys are the best. Special thanks to @simptri,Carlos Heuberger, GhostCat and Onkar Musale